# an other ! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost

Tags: floats, books

I am writing a big LaTeX document (doctoral thesis). And I've adopted a "complex" structure with `\include{}` and `\input{}` and I have obviously :

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20 \chapter
             {Des modèles théoriques aux modèles opératifs, l'espace com...
```

EDIT : a "small" exemple

```
  \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes} % csquotes va utiliser la langue définie dans babel
\usepackage{etex} %pour repousser le nombre packages utilisable
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{eurosym} %pour avoir le symbole euro
\usepackage{footnote} %pour pouvoir avoir des footnot dans le tableau
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}%%pour faire les encadré dans la partie 2 par exemple
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[maxfloats=35]{morefloats}%une solution pour pas se taper l'erreur page 205
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{todonotes}%pour pouvoir mettre des annotations et commentaires dans les marges
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}%figure intégrer dans le texte de manière flotante
\usepackage{newunicodechar} %pour les caractères speciaux dans les biblio par exemple!
\usepackage[
  %refsegment=chapter,
  %refsegment=part,
  %uniquelist=false, %pour utiliser la même balise qu'on ait une ou plusieurs ref biblio dans la balise
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  %style=authoryear-comp,
  %style=authoryear-icomp,
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  backend=biber,  
  sorting=nyt, %appel biblio par name year title ... fonctionne pas trop
  doi=true, 
  url=false, 
  eprint=false, 
  hyperref=true,
  firstinits=true,
  uniquename=init
]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\section{Le modèle LAME : la montagne, un espace de ségrégation, un espace de valorisation}\label{chap:LAME}


    \subsection*{Introduction}


    \subsection{Quelles sont les sources de dynamiques des surfaces viticoles?}\label{part:sources_dyn_viticole}



        \subsubsection{Où est la viticulture}\label{part:ou_est_la_viticulture}
        Sur l'AOC du Cru Banyuls comme dans le contexte du val di Cembra\todo{compléter les analyse avec les données de Cembra}, les possibilités offertes par la mécanisation sont rapidement limitées. De manière empirique, on constate que la viticulture a eu tendance à s'installer sur les versant (fig. \ref{fig:viticulture_moutain} et \ref{fig:vine_localisation}), abandonnant les zones plus plates à l'urbanisation (pour sur Banyuls) ou a des cultures plus exigentes (vallée de l'Adige (Trentino-Italie)). Ces observations sont corroborées par une serie d'analyse statistique et spatiales \footnote{Toutes ces analyses ont été réalisées avec le logiciel R \autocite{r_development_core_team_r:_2014}, à l'aide des packages rgdal \autocite{bivand_rgdal:_2013} pour le traitement des données spatiales, et ggplot2 \autocite{wickham_ggplot2:_2009} pour les sorties graphiques}.
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/banyuls_agouilles_small}\label{fig:slope_banyuls}}
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/cembra_montagne_small}\label{fig:cembra_slope_montagne}}
                \caption{Photos des vignobles de Banyuls-sur-Mer (Pyrénées-Orientales, France) fig. \subref{fig:slope_banyuls}, et cembra (Trentino, Italie) fig. \subref{fig:cembra_slope_montagne}}.
                \label{fig:viticulture_moutain}
        \end{figure}

        \begin{figure}
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/localisation_vine}
                \caption{Localisation des parcelles viticoles (en violet) sur l'AOC cru Banyuls (2013)}
                \label{fig:vine_localisation}
        \end{figure}



        \begin{table}
            \centering
                \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}    
                    \hline
                    & Sommes des carrés & dl & Somme moy des carrés & F & p\\
                    \hline
                    Intergroupe & 22.0 & 1 & 21.97 & 127.95 & p<0.001\\
                    Résidus & 3623.8 & 21107 & 0.1717 & &\\
                    Total & 3654 & 210108 & & &\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Analyse de variance (ANOVA) sur la relation entre les parcelles viticoles et la pente moyenne de celles-ci (c.f. fig. \ref{fig:density_slope_cadastre})}\label{table:anova_slope_cadastre}
        \end{table}

        \begin{figure}
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/cadastre_VS_viticulture}
                \caption{Estimation par noyau de la pente des populations de parcelles viticoles et non viticoles}
                \label{fig:density_slope_cadastre}
        \end{figure}


        \subsubsection{Des échanges foncier : lieu d'interactions ?}

        \begin{table}
            \centering
                \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}    
                    \hline
                    & Sommes des carrés & dl & Somme moy des carrés & F & p\\
                    \hline
                    Intergroupe & 1573 & 1 & 1572.96 & 10.591 & p<0.01\\
                    Résidus & 676966 & 4558 & 148.5 & &\\
                    Total & 678539 & 4559 & & &\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Analyse de variance (ANOVA) sur la relation entre les parcelles échangée et parcelles conservées vis-à-vis de leurs valeurs de pente moyennes (c.f. fig. \ref{fig:rup_density_plots_echange})}\label{table:anova_slope}
        \end{table}

        \begin{figure} %script R analyse_stat_parcelles_slope.R
            \centering
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/density_plot_2011_2013}\label{fig:rup_density_plots_echange}}
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/density_plot_failed}\label{fig:rup_density_plot_failed}}\\
                \caption{Estimation par noyau de la pente des populations de parcelles viticoles (fig. \subref{fig:rup_density_plots_echange}, pour les parcelles échangées entre 2011 et 2013) (fig. \subref{fig:rup_density_plot_failed}, pour les parcelles abandonnées entre 2011 et 2013) sur l'AOC cru Banyuls}.
                \label{fig:density_ggplot_failed_changed}
        \end{figure}

        \subsubsection{Lieu d'extension ou de contraction du vignoble ?}\label{part:contraction_paysagere}


        \begin{table} %%% script R scrupt_parcelles_colonisé_abandonner_R
            \centering
                \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}    
                    \hline
                    & Sommes des carrés & dl & Somme moy des carrés & F & p\\
                    \hline
                    Intergroupe & 337 & 1 & 336.73 & 2.207 & ns\\
                    Résidus & 748241 & 4904 & 152.58 & &\\
                    Total & 748578 & 4905 & & &\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Analyse de variance (ANOVA) sur la relation entre les parcelles abandonnées et celles encore cultivées en 2013 et la pente moyenne de celles-ci \small{(résultats non significatifs \textit{ns})}, c.f. fig. \ref{fig:rup_density_plot_failed}}\label{table:anova_slope_failed}
        \end{table}

        \begin{table}%%% script R scrupt_parcelles_colonisé_abandonner_R
            \centering
                \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}    
                    \hline
                    & Sommes des carrés & dl & Somme moy des carrés & F & p\\
                    \hline
                    Intergroupe & 2 & 1 & 2.428 & 0.0164 & ns\\
                    Résidus & 693671 & 4684 & 148.094 & &\\
                    Total & 693673 & 4685 & & &\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Analyse de variance (ANOVA) sur la relation entre les parcelles colonisées entre 2011 et 2013 et les parcelles qui sont restées entretenues et la pente moyenne de celles-ci \small{(résultats non significatifs \textit{ns})}}\label{table:anova_colonized}
        \end{table}


        \begin{figure} %% creé par le script script_localisation_map.R
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/isochrone.png}
                \caption{cartographie des temps de parcours sur l'AOC du cru Banyuls}
                \label{fig:isochrone_AOC_banyuls}
        \end{figure}                


        \begin{table}
            \centering
                \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}    
                    \hline
                    & Sommes des carrés & dl & Somme moy des carrés & F & p\\
                    \hline
                    Intergroupe & 205 & 1 & 205.309 & 9.897 & p<0.001\\
                    Résidus & 52195 & 2516 & 20.745 & &\\
                    Total & 52400 & 2517 & & &\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Analyse de variance (ANOVA) sur la relation entre les parcelles abandonnées et cultivées vis-à-vis leur accessibilité \small{(résultats significatifs)}, c.f. fig. \ref{fig:lup_density_acces_failed} }\label{table:anova_acces_failed}
        \end{table}


        \begin{table}
            \centering
                \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}    
                    \hline
                    & Sommes des carrés & dl & Somme moy des carrés & F & p\\
                    \hline
                    Intergroupe & 9 & 1 & 9.1235 & 0.4503 & ns\\
                    Résidus & 52195 & 44107 & 20.2603 & &\\
                    Total & 52204 & 44108 & & &\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Analyse de variance (ANOVA) sur la relation entre les parcelles colonisée par rapport à celles héritées vis-à-vis de leur accessibilité \small{(résultats non significatifs \textit{ns})}, c.f. fig. \ref{fig:rup_density_plot_colonized_acces}}\label{table:anova_acces_colonized}
        \end{table}             

        \begin{figure} %figures construite avec le scripts script/analyse_stat_parcelles_acces.R
            \centering
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/density_plot_failed_acces}\label{fig:lup_density_acces_failed}}
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/density_plot_colonized_acces}\label{fig:rup_density_plot_colonized_acces}}\\
                \caption{Estimation par noyau de l'accessibilité de la population de parcelles viticoles (fig. \subref{fig:lup_density_acces_failed}, pour les parcelles abandonnées entre 2011 et 2013) (fig. \subref{fig:rup_density_plot_colonized_acces}, pour les parcelles colonisées entre 2011 et 2013) sur l'AOC cru Banyuls}.
                \label{fig:density_ggplot_colonVSfailed_acces}
        \end{figure}




    \subsection{Contexte de la modélisation}\label{part:context_model_LAME} 

    \begin{table}
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{l c c}  
                \hline
                 & AOC Banyuls-Collioure & Val di Cembas\\
                \hline
                Surface viticole & 219ha & 4506ha \\
                Altitude médiane & 189 & 780.8 \\
                pente médiane & 18.3 & 26.9\\
                Nombre de viticulteurs & 223 & NA \\
                Nombre de coopératives & 3 & 1 \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{valeurs résumées sur la zone de travail (9$km^2$)}\label{table:resume_banyuls_cembras}
    \end{table}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/banyuls_DEM_rasterVIS}\label{fig:lup_DEM_banyuls}}
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/banyuls_slope_rasterVIS}\label{fig:rup_slope_banyuls}}\\
            \caption{Altitudes (fig. \subref{fig:lup_DEM_banyuls}, en mètres), et pentes (fig. \subref{fig:rup_slope_banyuls}, en degré) sur la zone de modélisation dans le bassin de la Baillaury sur la commune de Banyuls-sur-Mer (Pyrénées orientales, France)}
             \label{fig:small_map_banyuls}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/cembra_DEM_rasterVIS}\label{fig:lup_DEM_cembra}}
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/cembra_slope_rasterVIS}\label{fig:rup_slope_cembra}}\\
            \caption{Altitudes (fig. \subref{fig:lup_DEM_cembra}, en mètres), et pentes (fig. \subref{fig:rup_slope_cembra}, en degré) sur la zone de modélisation dans la haute vallée suspendue du Val di Cembra (Trentino, Italie)}
             \label{fig:small_map_cembra}
    \end{figure}

    \subsection{Matériels et Méthodes : ODD}


    \subsubsection{Développement du modèle}

        \begin{figure}
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/uml_LAME}
                \caption{Diagramme de classes UML du modèle Lame}\todo{présenter UML}
                \label{fig:uml_lame}
        \end{figure}


        \begin{figure}
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/scheduling}
                \caption{Ordonnancement des processus qui entre en dans LAME}
                \label{fig:scheduling_lame}
        \end{figure}

    \subsubsection{Conceptes d'élaboration}

    \begin{figure}
            \centering
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/exploration_repetition/echantillon1010}\label{fig:lame_5ech_10}}
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/exploration_repetition/echantillon1020}\label{fig:lame_5ech_20}}
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/exploration_repetition/echantillon1030}\label{fig:lame_5ech_30}}
                \caption{Evalusation de la stochastisté des résultats du modèle LAME sur 10 \subref{fig:lame_5ech_10}, 20 \subref{fig:lame_5ech_20}et 30 \subref{fig:lame_5ech_30} réplications d'un m\^eme jeux de paramètre}
                \label{fig:lame_stochastiq}
        \end{figure}



    \subsubsection{Détails} % Implementation Details
    \label{part:Details_LAME}


        \begin{table}
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{lcc}
                    \hline 
                    variable & description & valeurs \\ 
                    \hline 
                    NbVinegrower & nombre de viticulteurs & 300 \\ 
                    InitialCapital & Capital de départ des viticulteurs & 5000 \\ 
                    prix\_kg & Prix du raison au kg & 1.5 \\
                    rendement\_hl/ha & Rendement en hectolitre/ha & 2600\\ 
                    cout\_ha & Coût de production fixe par ha & 2300 \\ 
                    FrontPrice & Prix du front pionnier & 33000 \\ 
                    reserveSellPrice & Prix d'achat des parcelles d'occasion & 17000 \\ 
                    \hline 
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Valeurs d'initialisation du mod\`ele}\label{table:init_LAME}
            \end{center}
        \end{table}




%       \begin{figure}
%           \begin{center}
%               \includegraphics[width=200px]{partie2/acidity_gis/img/WK}
%               \caption{capacité de travail d'un Homme en ha en fonction de la pente en \%}
%               \label{fig:workingCapacity_LAME}
%           \end{center}
%       \end{figure}
        La figure \ref{fig:workingCapacity_LAME} nous permet d'observer le résultat du calcul de $Ct$. Quand la pente est de 0\% un Homme est capable de cultivé 10 ha, tandis que si la pente est de 45\% il ne sera en mesure de cultivé que 2ha.

 \subsection{Résultats}
    \subsubsection{calibration et exploration : espace abstrait, espace physique}


    \begin{figure}%%%%%graphes issu du script R exp_calibre_slope_distance.R
        \centering
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/boxplot_med_slope}\label{fig:up_median_slope_LAME}}\\
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/boxplot_surfaceViti_slope}\label{fig:down_surfaceViti_LAME}}
            \caption{Graphiques en boite à moustache reprenant la pente médiane des parcelles viticole \subref{fig:up_median_slope_LAME}, et la surface viticole \subref{fig:down_surfaceViti_LAME} dans une espace abstrait.}
             \label{fig:mediane_slope_and_surface_viti_LAME}
    \end{figure}


        \begin{figure}%%%%%graphes issu du script R exp_calibre_slope_distance_GIS.R
        \centering
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/GIS_boxplot_med_slope}\label{fig:up_GIS_median_slope_LAME}}\\
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/GIS_boxplot_surfaceViti_slope}\label{fig:down_GIS_surfaceViti_LAME}}
            \caption{Graphiques en boite à moustache reprenant la pente médiane des parcelles viticole \subref{fig:up_GIS_median_slope_LAME}, et la surface viticole \subref{fig:down_GIS_surfaceViti_LAME}  dans un espaces réel.}
             \label{fig:GIS_mediane_slope_and_surface_viti_LAME}
    \end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%Cette figure ne réponde pas aux questions  
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/boxplot_hillViti_slope}\label{fig:up_hillViti_slope_LAME}}\\
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/boxplot_vitiRuined_slope}\label{fig:down_ruinedViti_LAME}}
            \caption{Graphiques en boite à moustache reprenant en \ref{fig:up_hillViti_slope_LAME} la proportion de viticulteur en "zone de pente", et en \ref{fig:down_ruinedViti_LAME} la proportion de viticulteurs qui ont fait faillites.}
             \label{fig:hillViti_failled_viti_LAME}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{figure} %%%script issu du script analyse_stat_parcelles.R
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/LAME_FWHM}
            \caption{Courbe de densité sur les pentes des parcelles échangées avec la délimitation de l'intervalle FWHM}
             \label{fig:FWHM_LAME}
    \end{figure} 


    \begin{figure} %%%script issu du script traitement_simu_alpha_beta.R
        \centering
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/density_plot_simlated2}\label{fig:up_abstract_LAME_slope_exange}}\\
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/GISdensity_plot_simlated2}\label{fig:down_GIS_LAME_slope_exange}}
            \caption{Courbe de densité des pentes moyennes pour les parcelles échangées durant les simulations dans un contexte abstrait \subref{fig:up_abstract_LAME_slope_exange} et dans un contexte SIG \subref{fig:down_GIS_LAME_slope_exange}}
             \label{fig:echanged_simulation_GIS_lame}
    \end{figure} 
    attention l'ambiguité ici est qu'on travail sur les pente moyenne sur toute l'AOC alors que les pentes moyenne de la simulation sont sur la zone de 9ha !!!



    \begin{figure} %%%%%graphes issu du script R exp_calibre_slope_distance.R
        \centering
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/alpha20_boxplot_med_slope}\label{fig:up_alpha20_median_slope_LAME}}
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/alpha20_boxplot_surfaceViti_slope}\label{fig:down_alpha20_surfaceViti_LAME}}\\
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/alpha20_boxplot_hillViti_slope}\label{fig:up_alpha20_hillViti_slope_LAME}}
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/alpha20_boxplot_vitiRuined_slope}\label{fig:down_alpha20_ruinedViti_LAME}}
            \caption{truc truc}
             \label{fig:mediane_slope_and_surface_viti_alpha20_LAME}
    \end{figure}

    \subsubsection{Résultats prospectifs : la montagne entre attraction et répulsion}

    %%l'aspect social : repulsif de la montagne -> Le capital des vitis?
    \begin{figure} %%%%%graphes issu du script R partie2_propective.R
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/boxplot_capital_slope_plain}
            \caption{Répartition du capital entre les viticulteurs de plaine et de montagne (avec $\beta = 60$ )}\label{fig:Capital_hill_plain}
    \end{figure}

    %%la montagne fragmente les exploitations
    \begin{figure} %%%%%graphes issu du script R partie2_propective.R
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/boxplot_fragmentation_slope_plain}
            \caption{Fragmentation des exploitations selon leurs lieux d'implantation en plaine ou en montagne}\label{fig:fragmentation_hill_plain}
    \end{figure}  

    \paragraph*{La montagne, le faire valoir des riches}

    \hspace{1em}

    %%Le faire valoir des riches
    \begin{figure} %%%%%graphes issu du script R partie2_propective.R
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/boxplot_hillVSrunied_slope_plain}
            \caption{Évolution de la population de viticulteur ruiné,  proportion des viticulteurs en activité qui ont des leur exploitation sur des zones de pentes, et surface viticole totale dans le modèle au cour du temps dans un espace asbtrait.}\label{fig:riuned_hill_plain}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{figure} %%%%%graphes issu du script R partie2_propective.R
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/GIS_boxplot_hillVSrunied_slope_plain}
            \caption{Évolution de la population de viticulteur ruiné,  proportion des viticulteurs en activité qui ont des leur exploitation sur des zones de pentes, et surface viticole totale dans le modèle au cour du temps dans un espace SIG}\label{fig:GIS_riuned_hill_plain}
    \end{figure}



    \subsubsection{Pente et distance : contraintes ou opportunité?}

 \subsection*{Conclusion prospective}


\section{Le modèle CIVIsMe }\label{part:modele_civisme}

    \subsection*{Introduction}

    \subsection{Contexte de la modélisation : La coopération entre marque et terroir}   

    \begin{figure} %%%script issu du script data_union_coop.R
            \centering
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{partie2/CIVIsMe/img/map_nb_coop_dep}\label{fig:map_nb_coop_dep}}\\
            \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{partie2/CIVIsMe/img/map_c2c_dep}\label{fig:map_nb_adherent_dep}}
                \caption{Mise en regarde du nombre de coopératives par département \subref{fig:map_nb_coop_dep}, et du ratio du nombre d'adhérents sur le nombre de coopérative par département \subref{fig:map_nb_adherent_dep}}
                \label{fig:muli_map_nb_coop_adherant}
        \end{figure}

    \begin{figure} %%%script issu du script github bazaRd/map_coop.R
            \centering
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{partie2/CIVIsMe/img/pct_prod_deptVSnationnale}\label{fig:map_volume_dep_fr}}\\
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{partie2/CIVIsMe/img/pct_coop_departements2013}\label{fig:map_volume_coop}}
                \caption{Mise en regarde de la part des volumes produits en France par département \subref{fig:map_volume_dep_fr}, et de la part des volumes départementaux produit en coopérative \subref{fig:map_volume_coop}}
                \label{fig:muli_map_volume_coop}
    \end{figure}


        \begin{figure} %%%script issu du script traitement_simu_alpha_beta.R
            \centering
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/CIVIsMe/img/pie_surface_by_coop}\label{fig:up_pie_surface_coop}}\\
                \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/CIVIsMe/img/pie_producteurs_by_coop}\label{fig:down_pie_producteur_coop}}
                \caption{Le poid de la coopération en surface planté (ha) \subref{fig:up_pie_surface_coop} et en nombre de producteurs \subref{fig:down_pie_producteur_coop} sur l'AOC du cru Banyuls}
                \label{fig:pie_coop_producteurs_surfaces}
        \end{figure} 

    \subsection{Matériels et Méthodes : ODD}

    \subsubsection{Développement du modèle}

        \begin{figure}
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/CIVIsMe/img/UML_classes}
                \caption{Diagramme de classes UML du modèle CIVIsMe}
                \label{fig:uml_CIVIsMe}
        \end{figure}


        \begin{figure}
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/CIVIsMe/img/scheduling}
                \caption{Ordonnancement des processus qui entre en jeux dans CIVIsMe}
                \label{fig:scheduling_civisme}
        \end{figure}


    \subsubsection{Conceptes d'élaboration}

    \subsubsection{Details} % Implementation Details

        \begin{figure}
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/CIVIsMe/img/regression_capital}
                \caption{Deux exemples de régression linéaire en fonction du capital économique des agents}
                \label{fig:lm_CIVIsMe}
        \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

It's not small but at least it produce the float error

Comment: The usual way to get that error is to use a float somewhere that is not allowed (although it's more likely to give `{Not in outer par mode` in that case.) It is unrelated to `\input` so you should be able to make a small example by the usual technique, of starting with a copy of the document and removing any text or package you can remove while still showing the error.

Comment: which part you want to see ? I imagine the `\input{}` before the error?

Comment: If you keep removing things while still generating the error I would have expected that you can make a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` of less than 100 lines or so and then you could add the complete document to your question, so people can reproduce the error and debug it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a figure or a table that got lost. Other things are "floats" too. E.g. this would trigger the error as the `\marginpar` can't escape: `\parbox{1cm}{text\marginpar{blabal}}`

Comment: nothing like that in my document

Comment: I made a not small example

Comment: @UlrikeFischer good guess:-)

Comment: Another example would be a `\marginpar` inside a `\footnote` (as I just found out with a similar custom todo-reminder).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Ulrike guessed you have a marginpar in a minipage, or more exactly

```
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{partie2/LAME/img/uml_LAME}
            \caption{Diagramme de classes UML du modèle Lame}%\todo{présenter UML}
            \label{fig:uml_lame}
    \end{figure}
```

If you comment out the `\todo` as here the error goes.
(If you had removed un-needed packages such as `amsmath`, `babel` etc you would have found this, I just removed things until I tried removing `todonotes` when the error went.